# Map a literal address to a section

Tags: c, elf

Given a literal address, how can I determine which section that address falls in?  Here is an example.  From a disassembly of a program, made with 'objdump', I obtain a literal address 0x8048520:

80483ea:       c7 45 f4 20 85 04 08    movl   $0x8048520,-0xc(%ebp)
    ...

On my platform (Linux 2.6.39, Gentoo) I can obtain a listing of sections simply by running 'less' on the ELF file, and see that this address falls within the .rodata section:

```
[15] .rodata           PROGBITS        08048518 000518 000016 00   A  0   0  4
...
```

However, I'm looking for a convenient way to do the same thing that does not require visually scanning through and comparing addresses.  Suggestions?

Comment: readelf -S your_program_name > out.txt, and then parse out.txt to get the required value.

Comment: You could also just parse the ELF headers yourself. Read the beginning of the file to get the `Ehdr`, then follow its pointer to the `Shdr` which contains a list of sections. The relevant definitions are in elf.h.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using your example address of 0x8048520:

```
objdump -s --start-address=0x8048520 --stop-address=0x8048521 elf_file | grep section | awk '{ print $4 }' | cut -d':' -f 1
```

In your example, the output of this command would be:

```
.rodata
```

Comment: Nice solution!  And you can use the bash feature $((addr + 1)) to avoid having to manually add one to the address.